# NSTokenField delegate: ( - tokenField:shouldAddObjects:atIndex: ) doesn't work when it is plain style

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstokenfield

i have NSTokenField in my app. i want it in plain style (just want accept one value not more). so i want validate input text from array by using delegate [- tokenField:shouldAddObjects:atIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstokenfielddelegate/1524376-tokenfield?language=objc) 
but when style in plain , this delegate not run. when i put back style to default. it works.

it my delegate code

```
- (NSArray *)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField shouldAddObjects:(NSArray *)tokens atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSMutableArray *validTokens = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *supplierNames = [ary_suppliersFinal valueForKey:@"SupplierName"];   
    for (NSString *oneToken in tokens)
    {
        if ([supplierNames containsObject:oneToken ])
        {
            [validTokens addObject:oneToken];
        }
    }
    return validTokens;
}
```

what is wrong? what should i do to make NSTokenField in plain style , only accpet one token, validate token from an array?

Comment: Can't you use a plain text field and validate the value?

Comment: yes, in plain , validate token doesn't work